# How to pipe stdin to a child and execl cat in C

Tags: c, unix, fork, pipe

In the code below, I am simply trying to send a file via stdin to a child process which will exec the cat OS command.  The code compiles fine.  Here is how I call it from the command line:

```
$ ./uniquify < words.txt
```

However, when I run it I get a seg fault error. I am really having a hard time understanding how the flow if information is supposed to work through pipes to children.  I am trying to make the code as simple as possible, so I can understand it, but it is not yet making sense.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define NUM_CHILDREN 2

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{          
  pid_t catPid;                        
  int   writeFds[NUM_CHILDREN];        
  int   catFds[2];                      
  int   c = 0;
  FILE  *writeToChildren[NUM_CHILDREN]; 

  //create a pipe
  (void) pipe(catFds);

  if ((catPid = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("cat fork failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  //this is the child case
  if (catPid == 0) {
    //close the write end of the pipe
    close(catFds[1]);

    //close stdin?
    close(0);

    //duplicate the read side of the pipe
    dup(catFds[0]);

    //exec cat
    execl("/bin/cat", "cat", (char *) 0);
    perror("***** exec of cat failed");
    exit(20);
  }  
  else { //this is the parent case
    //close the read end of the pipe
    close(catFds[0]);

    int p[2];

    //create a pipe
    pipe(p);

    writeToChildren[c] = fdopen(p[1], "w");
  } //only the the parent continues from here

  //close file descriptor so the cat child can exit
  close(catFds[1]);

  char words[NUM_CHILDREN][50];

  //read through the input file two words at a time
  while (fscanf(stdin, "%s %s", words[0], words[1]) != EOF) {

    //loop twice passing one of the words to each rev child
    for (c = 0; c < NUM_CHILDREN; c++) {
      fprintf(writeToChildren[c], "%s\n", words[c]);
    }    
  }

  //close all FILEs and fds by sending and EOF
  for (c = 0; c < NUM_CHILDREN; c++) {
    fclose(writeToChildren[c]);
    close(writeFds[c]);
  }

  int status = 0;

  //wait on all children
  for (c = 0; c < (NUM_CHILDREN + 1); c++) {
    wait(&status);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `writeToChildren`, so you are calling `fprintf` on a bad `FILE *`.

Comment: so adding something like this?  
       writeToChildren[c] = fdopen(p[1], "w");

Comment: I edited the code and added the following to the parent code:  
    int p[2];

    //create a pipe
    pipe(p);

    writeToChildren[c] = fdopen(p[1], "w");

Comment: I am still getting a seg fault core dump error...

Comment: Your code writing to pipes assumes there will be two child processes; the code creating processes only creates one child process.  This leads to some of your problems.  You don't see to have as many close calls as necessary (after `dup(catFds[0])` you need `close(catFds[0])`, for example).  You don't include error checking on system calls.

Comment: I have `close(catFds[0])` in the parent, do I need it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question seems to be about understanding how pipes and forks work, I hope below programs can help you. Please notice that this is for illustration only. It wouldn't qualify for commercial implementation, but I wanted to keep it short!

You can compile the two programs as follows:

```
cc pipechild.c -o pipechild
cc pipeparent.c -o pipeparent
```

Then execute with `./pipeparent`

**pipeparent.c source**

```
/* pipeparent.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MESSAGE     "HELLO!\n"
#define INBUFSIZE   80
#define RD      0   // Read end of pipe
#define WR      1   // Write end of pipe

int main(void)
{
    int ptocpipe[2];    // Parent-to-child pipe
    int ctoppipe[2];    // Chile-to-parent pipe
    pid_t   childpid;   // Process ID of child
    char    inbuf[80];  // Input from child
    int rd;     // read() return
    int rdup;       // dup():ed stdin for child
    int wdup;       // dup():ed stdout for child
    char    *eol;       // End of line

    // Create pipe for writing to child
    if (pipe(ptocpipe) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe(ptocpipe) failed!\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Create pipe for writing back to parent
    if (pipe(ctoppipe) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe(ctoppipe) failed!\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Verify that one of the pipes are working by filling it first
    // in one end and then reading it from the other. The OS will
    // buffer the contents for us. Note, this is not at all necessary,
    // it's just to illustrate how it works!
    write(ptocpipe[WR], MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
    read(ptocpipe[RD], inbuf, INBUFSIZE);
    if (strlen(inbuf) != strlen(MESSAGE)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to flush the toilet!\n");
        return 6;
    } else {
        printf("Wrote to myself: %s", inbuf);
    }

    // Next, we want to launch some interactive program which
    // replies with exactly one line to each line we send to it,
    // until it gets tired and returns EOF to us.
    // First, we must clone ourselves by using fork(). Then the
    // child process must be replaced by the interactive program.
    // Problem is: How do we cheat the program to read its stdin
    // from us, and send its stdout back to us?
    switch (childpid = fork()) {
        case -1:    // Error
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent: fork() failed!\n");
        return 3;

        case 0:     // Child process
        // Close the ends we don't need. If not, we might
        // write back to ourselves!
        close(ptocpipe[WR]);
        close(ctoppipe[RD]);
        // Close stdin
        close(0);
        // Create a "new stdin", which WILL be 0 (zero)
        if ((rdup = dup(ptocpipe[RD])) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed dup(stdin)\n");
            return 4;
        }
        // Close stdout
        close(1);
        // Create a "new stdout", which WILL be 1 (one)
        if ((wdup = dup(ctoppipe[WR])) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed dup(stdout)\n");
            return 5;
        }
        // For debugging, verify stdin and stdout
        fprintf(stderr, "rdup: %d, wdup %d\n", rdup, wdup);
        // Overload current process by the interactive
        // child process which we want to execute.
        execlp("./pipechild", "pipechild", (char *) NULL);
        // Getting here means we failed to launch the child
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent: execl() failed!\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // This code is executed by the parent only!

    // Close the ends we don't need, to avoid writing back to ourself
    close(ptocpipe[RD]);
    close(ctoppipe[WR]);
    // Write one line to the child and expect a reply, or EOF.
    do {
        write(ptocpipe[WR], MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
        if ((rd = read(ctoppipe[RD], inbuf, INBUFSIZE)) > 0) {
            // Chop off ending EOL
            if ((eol = rindex(inbuf, '\n')) != NULL)
                *eol = '\0';
            printf("Parent: Read \"%s\" from child.\n", inbuf);
        }
    } while (rd > 0);

    fprintf(stderr, "Parent: Child done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**pipechild.c source**

```
/* pipechild.c
 * Note - This is only for illustration purpose!
 * To be stable, we should catch/ignore signals,
 * and use select() to read.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCOUNT    5   // Maximum input lines toread
#define INBUFSIZE   80  // Buffer size

int main(void)
{
    char    buff[INBUFSIZE];
    int remains = MAXCOUNT;
    pid_t   mypid;
    char    *eol;

    mypid = getpid();   // Process-ID
    fprintf(stderr, "Child %d: Started!\n", mypid);

    // For each line read, write one tostdout.
    while (fgets(buff, INBUFSIZE, stdin) && remains--) {
        // Chop off ending EOL
        if ((eol = rindex(buff, '\n')) != NULL)
            *eol = '\0';
        // Debug to console
        fprintf(stderr, "Child %d: I got %s. %d remains.\n",
            mypid, buff, 1 + remains);
        // Reply to parent
        sprintf(buff, "Child %d: %d remains\n", mypid, 1 + remains);
        write(1, buff, strlen(buff));
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Child %d: I'm done!\n", mypid);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some things things I deliberately excluded to avoid too much complexity: 1) Asynchronous communication isn't possible. You need to use select() for that, and use unblocking reads. 2) Low-level writes from child is only supported. 3) No need for the parent to write and read it's own pipe at the beginning, but this is to illustrate it can be done, and that you have to close one end to avoid getting data back to you. And there's other useless garbage code here as well you also can remove.

Comment: Is there a simple way for the parent process to read from multiple pipes at the same time? The simplest sane thing I can think of is to spawn one thread for each pipe... and use blocking reads. (Non-blocking read in a single thread... seems like an irresponsible use of a devices battery.) Is that what I should be doing?